# "Rich Text Editor" automatically appears at the top in ckeditor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

When I use the ckeditor5 text editor similar to the example code below, a text with the title "Rich Text Editor" automatically appears at the top! My search to find and delete the relevant settings did not return any results. please guide me

```
 <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/25.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"> 
 </script>
 <div id="editor">
 </div>
   <script>
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I have same problem too, just removed parent "form-group" div and solved

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but I found interesting this thing:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/classic-editor.html

Here the classic editor, if you look at the DOM, there is the same label

```
<label class="ck ck-label ck-voice-label" id="ck-editor__label_[id]">Rich Text Editor</label>
```

but styles have

```
.ck.ck-voice-label {
    display: none;
}
```

So, we need to include also styles, or even copy them with modifications.
Actually, there is also a way to recreate editor view to custumize it, but I think all you need to do — use classic **build**, not editor. Classic build already have this style.